# Android location update while phone being inactive

Tags: android, geolocation

I´m currently developing an app which is working as a proximity alert, using the network provider.

Running several tests, I noticed that my phone sometimes is not receiving updates when the screen is turned off.

Is `LocationManager`  somehow affected by the phone´s standby?

Having reached my set destination, I turned my screen on and after some seconds (I request updates about every 60 seconds) my app suddenly gets a fresh and correct update. Especially when running Maps or other apps which use the network provider, my app does receive location updates more reliably.

Thanks for your answer in advance,
Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn´t find a solution but the problem. It is a nasty Android Bug, which prevents the system to send location updates with new coordinates when the device is in wakelock.

See here: [Issue on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10931)

I hope this might help anybody out there to solve some problems.

Answer (score 1):

When using `LocationManager`'s `addProximityAlert()` you have to be aware that if the screen goes to sleep the checks for proximity alerts only happen once every 4 minutes in order to conserve battery life.

Comment: I do not use the LocationManager's addProximityAlert, because I want to get updates more often than every 4 minutes.

Comment: @mgv Where did you get information? it dont see it in the api documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double, double, float, long, android.app.PendingIntent)